# MYSQL Current Year

Tags: mysql

I have a following SQL statement that should be returns the month, ph1, ph2 and ph3 values where minimum values of next month - minimum values of previous month

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a1.date_time, '%M,%Y') AS month, 
    (a4.ph1_active_energy)*10 - a1.ph1_active_energy AS 'ph1', (a4.ph2_active_energy)*10 - a1.ph2_active_energy AS 'ph2', (a4.ph3_active_energy)*10 - a1.ph3_active_energy AS 'ph3' 
    FROM powerpro a1 

    JOIN (SELECT MONTH(date_time) month, MIN(date_time) AS min FROM powerpro GROUP BY MONTH(date_time) 
    ) a2 ON a1.date_time = a2.min 

    JOIN (SELECT MONTH(date_time) month, MIN(date_time) AS min FROM powerpro GROUP BY DATE(date_time) 
    ) a3 ON DATE(a1.date_time) = a3.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY 

    JOIN powerpro 

    a4 ON a4.date_time = a3.min 

    WHERE YEAR(a1.date_time) = YEAR(CURDATE()) ORDER BY a1.date_time
```

I want to get only the records of current year. But script returns the empty result set.

What may be going wrong. Can any one help me ?